# How Do "App Lock" app work internally?

Tags: android, service, timertask

I need to develop app just like android App lock that opens password activity when app assigned application get launch. I have read below question but didn't find proper solution.
I just want to ask that what service or method they are using? how to know about any other app launch event?

In my current implementation, I have added a service and in MyService, I have added a timer to check currentApp and then I am comparing current app to assigned app.

I don't like this approach because timer takes lot of battery as well as device get slow.

```
public void isForeground(String myPackage){
        String currentApp="";

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
                    time - 1000 * 1000, time);
            if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                    mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),
                            usageStats);
                }
                if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                    currentApp = mySortedMap.get(
                            mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                }
            }
        } else {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            currentApp = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity .getPackageName();
        }
        processCurrentApp(currentApp,myPackage);

        }
```

Any one can help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

To get current active apps try

```
public boolean isConcernedAppIsInForeground() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> task = manager.getRunningTasks(5);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 20) {
            if (task.size() > 0) {
                ComponentName componentInfo = task.get(0).topActivity;
                for (int i = 0; pakageName != null && i < pakageName.size(); i++) {
                    if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(pakageName.get(i))) {
                        currentApp = pakageName.get(i);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            String mpackageName = manager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
            UsageStatsManager usage = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<UsageStats> stats = usage.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, 0, time);
            if (stats != null) {
                SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> runningTask = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                    runningTask.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                }
                if (runningTask.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"isEmpty Yes");
                    mpackageName = "";
                }else {
                    mpackageName = runningTask.get(runningTask.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                    Log.d(TAG,"isEmpty No : "+mpackageName);
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; pakageName != null && i < pakageName.size(); i++) {
                if (mpackageName.equals(pakageName.get(i))) {
                    currentApp = pakageName.get(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Check this open source project: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/AppLock/

Comment: My code is working. it can get current app as well. I just want to know what should I use to replace timer in service. How App lock work?